# opts_knit$set(unnames.chunk.label = "figs") doesn't change the default labels

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to change the default chunk labeling options in the knitr package as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup>>=
knitr::opts_knit$set(progress=TRUE, verbose=FALSE,unnamed.chunk.label="figs")
@

<<>>=
rnorm(10)
@

\end{document}
```

But the chunk label is "unnamed-chunk-1", not "figs-1".